# Composite and one-one functions.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, functions, examples-counterexamples

I wanted to know if $g \circ f$ is defined and is one-one then under what conditions will both $g$ and $f$ be one-one? Particularly is it possible if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$?

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are both finite *and the same size* then $g\circ f$ being one-to-one does imply that both $g$ and $f$ are one-to-one (*and indeed will imply that both are bijections*).  This need not hold for $A$ and $B$ of different cardinality and need not hold for $A$ and $B$ infinite.  For a counterexample of the infinite case, $A=B=\Bbb N$ and $f(n)=2n$ while $g(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\right\rfloor$ you have $f$ and $g\circ f$ are both one-to-one but $g$ is not.

Answer (score 1):

If $g\circ f$ is one-to-one, then $f$ is also one-to-one (it's a good exercise to prove this), but $g$ need not be. For example, if $f\colon\{x\}\to B$ and $g\colon B\to\{x\}$ (here $\{x\}$ is any singleton set), then $f$ and $g\circ f$ are automatically one-to-one, but $g$ itself is not when $\#B>1$.